# Python3 convert string words from Combobox to int value

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there anyway to convert or assign int value to strings ?

if i use this line, **self.months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]** 
the program gets the year and month and return the value to combobox.
But if i replace the int value in **self.month** to string like in the code bellow it will complain that it wants int.
as i understand .
**values** Specifies the list of values to display in the drop-down and **listbox.textvariabl** specifies a name whose value is linked to the widget value.

```
from tkinter import *
import calendar
from tkinter import ttk
class main:


    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.month = IntVar()
        self.year = IntVar()
        self.months = ["Jan","Feb","Mars","April","Maj","Jun","Juli","Aug","Sept","Okt","Nov","Dec"]
        print(self.months)
        self.years = (2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020)
        self.widgets()


    def widgets(self):
        Label(self.master,text="Kalender",font =("freesansbold",30),bd=10).pack()
        f = Frame(self.master,pady=10,padx=10)

        Label(f,text="Year",font =("freesansbold",12)).grid(row=0,column=0)
        Label(f,text='Month',font =("freesansbold",12)).grid(row=0,column=3,)

        year = ttk.Combobox(f,width=7,font =("freesansbold",12),values = self.years,textvariable = self.year)
        year.grid(row=0,column=2)
        year.current(4)

        mon = ttk.Combobox(f,width=7,font =("freesansbold",12),values = self.months,textvariable = self.month)
        mon.grid(row=0,column=4)
        mon.current(0)
        f.pack()

        self.area = Text(self.master,width=30,height=10,bd=5,font =("freesansbold",12))
        self.area.pack()
        Button(self.master,text="Get Kalender",font=("freesansbold",12),command=self.getcal).pack()

    def getcal(self):
        m = self.month.get()
        y = self.year.get()
        cal = calendar.month(y,m,1,2)
        self.area.delete(0.0,END)
        self.area.insert(0.0,cal)




root = Tk()
main(root)
root.title("just som stuff 1.0")
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(460, 350))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're trying to convert something like "April" or "July" to an integer. Python doesn't know how to do that.

Comment: Yes, but how do i do it manual ?

Comment: I am sure a method from `datetime` should be able to convert month names/abbreviation to a number value.

Answer (score 2):

First; you are using an `IntVar()` to associate with the value in the `mon` combobox. This will raise an exception as the contents are strings. Change the variable to `StringVar()` in the function `__init__()`.

```
self.month = StringVar()
```

Second; you try to access the calendar with the string from the `mon` combobox. This will raise an exception because the calendar only accepts integers. Below is an example of how to get an integer from the combobox: Find the index of the month-string in the list of months, then add one because list index starts at 0.

```
def getcal(self):
    m = self.months.index(self.month.get()) + 1
```